# Using QApplication::exec() in a function or class

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I want the following code to get the request url starting with `http://down.51en.com:88` during the web loading process , and then do other processing with the response object of  the url .
In my program,  once `targetUrl` is assigned a value , I want the function `targetUrlGetter(url)` to return it to the caller, however , the problem is that `QApplication::exec()` enters the main event loop so cannot  execute code at the end of the`targetUrlGetter()` function after the exec() call , thus the function cannot return , I have tried with `qApp.quit()` in `interceptRequest(self, info)` in order to tell the application to exit so that `targetUrlGetter(url)` can return , but the function still cannot return and the program even crashes on exit(tested on Win7 32bit), so how can I return the  `targetUrl` to  the caller program ?

The difficulties here are how to exit the Qt event loop without crash and return the request url to the caller.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.page = parent

    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        if info.requestUrl().toString().startswith('http://down.51en.com:88'):
            self.targetUrl = info.requestUrl().toString()
            print('----------------------------------------------', self.targetUrl)
            qApp.quit()

            # self.page.load(QUrl(''))


def targetUrlGetter(url=None):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    page = QWebEnginePage()
    globalSettings = page.settings().globalSettings()
    globalSettings.setAttribute(
        QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
    globalSettings.setAttribute(
        QWebEngineSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)
    profile = page.profile()
    webEngineUrlRequestInterceptor = WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(page)
    profile.setRequestInterceptor(webEngineUrlRequestInterceptor)
    page.load(QUrl(url))
    # view = QWebEngineView()
    # view.setPage(page)
    # view.show()
    app.exec_()
    return webEngineUrlRequestInterceptor.targetUrl


url = "http://www.51en.com/news/sci/everything-there-is-20160513.html"
# url = "http://www.51en.com/news/sci/obese-dad-s-sperm-may-influence-offsprin.html"
# url = "http://www.51en.com/news/sci/mars-surface-glass-could-hold-ancient-fo.html"
targetUrl = targetUrlGetter(url)
print(targetUrl)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. The script runs without error and prints/returns the requested url as expected. I don't see any reason why `exec()` should "hang". Are you sure there are no networking issues?

Comment: @ekhumoro sorry for my poor english , see the updated post again ! If you cannot see the exit crash , please test the code more than once on Windows

Comment: I cannot test on Windows. The script works fine on Linux. You need to do some basic debugging to see where the script fails. Does the web-page load properly? Use the [loadFinished signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#loadFinished) to check. Does `interceptRequest` ever get called, and if so, what is the output of `print(repr(info.requestUrl().toString()))`? Does the `if` statement ever evaluate to `True`?

Comment: @ekhumoro all works fine except the exit crash

Comment: Try using a global variable for `app`, and/or `page`. There is probably a garbage-collection issue (i.e. objects getting deleted in the wrong order).

Answer (score -1):

You should always initialize `QApplication` at the beginning of the program, and always call the `QApplication::exec` function at the end of the program.

Another thing is that `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor.interceptRequest` is a callback function which is called asynchronously. Since `info.requestUrl().toString()` is called inside the callback function, there is *no way* to `return` the result it synchronously.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.page = parent

    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        if info.requestUrl().toString().startswith('http://down.51en.com:88'):
            self.targetUrl = info.requestUrl().toString()
            print('----------------------------------------------', self.targetUrl)
            # Don't do thatDo you really want to exit the whole program?
            # qApp.quit()

            # Do something here, rather than return it.
            # It must be run asynchronously

            # self.page.load(QUrl(''))


def targetUrlGetter(url=None):
    page = QWebEnginePage()
    globalSettings = page.settings().globalSettings()
    globalSettings.setAttribute(
        QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
    globalSettings.setAttribute(
        QWebEngineSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)
    profile = page.profile()
    webEngineUrlRequestInterceptor = WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(page)
    profile.setRequestInterceptor(webEngineUrlRequestInterceptor)
    page.load(QUrl(url))
    # view = QWebEngineView()
    # view.setPage(page)
    # view.show()

    # Don't return this. It cannot be called synchronously. It must be called asynchronously.
    # return webEngineUrlRequestInterceptor.targetUrl

app = QApplication(sys.argv)  # always initialize QApplication at the beginning of the program
url = "http://www.51en.com/news/sci/everything-there-is-20160513.html"
# url = "http://www.51en.com/news/sci/obese-dad-s-sperm-may-influence-offsprin.html"
# url = "http://www.51en.com/news/sci/mars-surface-glass-could-hold-ancient-fo.html"
targetUrl = targetUrlGetter(url)
print(targetUrl)
app.exec_() # always call the QApplication::exec at the end of the program
```